# Elgamal Protocol Failure

Tags: encryption, public-key, signature, protocol-design, elgamal-signature

I'm having a difficult time trying to solve this problem.

> Suppose Alice uses the Elgamal signature scheme with 
>  $(\alpha,
>  \beta, p) = (2, 33384, 65539)$.  
>  She publishes the two signed
>   messages:
>  $(m_1, r_1, s_1) = (809, 18357, 1042)$ and $(m_2, r_2,
>  s_2) = (22505, 18357, 26272)$.
>  Find $a$ by setting up and solving
>   appropriate linear congruences. (I.e., don't compute the discrete
>   logarithm of beta directly)

I know that $\beta = \alpha^a \bmod p$, which in this case would be $33384 = 2^a \bmod 65539$.  However, I have no idea how to use the messages to set up congruences to solve for $a$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide a link?

Comment: This is a standard "same k attack". You should be able to take this attack on DSA and make it work against ElGamal Signatures

Answer (score 1):

1. Note the relation between $r_1$ and $r_2$
2. Infer the relationship internal variables need to have because of this
3. Write down the equations to calculate $(r_1,s_1),(r_2,s_2)$ and use the above relationship
4. Pretend the equations would be over $\mathbb R$ and solve the above system of equations for $a$
5. Now plug-in the values and actually perform the modular arithmetic
6. You now should have recovered the private key